# YouTube API Services Compliance Review

Tags: service, youtube, review

I have a project where I need to have the API quota increased significantly from the 10,000 daily hits, and I *think* this is being processed by Google as part of a YouTube API Services Compliance Review.

However, I have not had any response in over a week and the delay is putting the project at risk of a delayed launch and additional costs.

Does anyone know if this is normal and if there is a way to expedite the review, or speak to someone? Even pay for a higher tier of support?

Answer (score 0):

If you’ve filled the audit form https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form?hl=en properly, you should get a response within two weeks (Google reviews thousands of these, among other things to prevent abuse this is one of the processes that isn’t fully automated).

I recommend if your in a rush since your paying for credits you might as well open a second account and load balance between two or even three accounts; in your code you can create counters and swap before capping out the 24 hour term;  not sure what data you’re looking to extract but depends on what data you may be able to even use other services to supplement.

They will get back to you about your application; just requires massive patience.